# UITableVIew not working with UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have encountered a very strange behavior, when I implemented navigationController.
I have a LogInViewController with an UITableView,where cells are populated like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        return cellUsername;
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 1){
        return cellPassword;
    }
    else{
        return nil;
    }
}
```

cellUsername and cellPassword are Cells which I created on .xib.. 
And when i add this LogInViewController as a rootViewController in my appDelegate it works fine! 
I wanted to implement a navigationController, so I created RootViewController, with navController @property and in my appDelagate i called it like this

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];


RootViewController *rootView = [[RootViewController alloc]init];
rootView.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootView];

self.window.rootViewController = rootView.navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

And in my RootViewController on viewDidLoad I have this code:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
LogInViewController *loginView = [[LogInViewController alloc]init];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:loginView animated:YES];
```

It opens my LogInViewController,but only the first cell,cellUsername is added to my UiTableView, what is wrong? 
Am still a beginner,so I might be missing something stupid probably.. but it works wihout navigationController,so am pretty confused.. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with your problem, but you shouldn't be using this line in your viewDidLoad:

```
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
```

Your RootViewController is already embedded in a navigation controller, so you can just use self.navigationController to get a reference to it.

I'm also not sure about this code, it may be ok, but it's not the way it's usually done:

```
RootViewController *rootView = [[RootViewController alloc]init];
rootView.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootView];
self.window.rootViewController = rootView.navController;
```

The usual way to do it is like this:

```
RootViewController *rootView = [[RootViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootView];
self.window.rootViewController = nav;
```

Answer (score 0):

in AppDelegate file

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];


RootViewController *rootView = [[RootViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootView];

self.window.rootViewController =  navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Further there is no need to create another navigationController in the viewDidLoad of the RootViewController  class

Comment: Thank you for a quick response, did everything you said but still, I get only one cell in my tableview.

Comment: the number of cells depends on the dataSource array of the tableView..If that array contains 1 object then this scenario is right